# Why does yielding a mutated object in a javascript generator result in different behavior when converted to array?

Tags: javascript, generator

I have a generator function `foo` written in JavaScript.

```js
function* foo() {
    const bar = { a: 0, b: 0 };
    yield bar;

    bar.a += 1;
    yield bar;

    bar.b += 10;
    yield bar;
}
```

The function `foo` takes no parameter but keeps an internal object `bar` that is used for yielding. The function can yield 3 times, each time returning a different value.

The expected behavior is observed when calling `next().value` on the resulting object.

```js
const baz = foo()
console.log(baz.next().value)   // => { a: 0, b: 0 }
console.log(baz.next().value)   // => { a: 1, b: 0 }
console.log(baz.next().value)   // => { a: 1, b: 10 }
```

However, when using the `Array.from` method to create an array from the resulting iterator, a strange behavior is observed instead.

```js
console.log(Array.from(foo()))  // => [ { a: 1, b: 10 }, { a: 1, b: 10 }, { a: 1, b: 10 } ]
```

The final object is returned for every yield instead of return the value each time `yield` was called! This behavior happens in both node 10.13 and node 12.7. Why is this happening? Shouldn't the results be the same for both cases?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference so in the end you have an array with 3 references to the same object.

Comment: @NenadVracar Where is it passing by reference? I can't seem to see the passing here.

Comment: In other words, you only create a single object, not three.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yeah, but shouldn't the `Array.from` method be getting a different value each time `yield` is called?

Comment: `bar` has a value that is reference to the one same object `{ a: 0, b: 0 }` that you are modifying and on each yield you yield `bar`

Comment: @krismath The value you return is still referencing the same object. But the same applies for your `baz.next().value`. If you store the first in a variable, call `next()` an additional two times, you will see that the first also changed. See https://jsfiddle.net/sLofk3ua/

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks guys. Seems that I am rusty about object references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in javascript objects are passed by reference you are modifying the same object after each yield and in the end you have an array with 3 references to the same object in memory in its final state.

To get an array with different objects you would have to create new objects on each yield, for example using object spread syntax.

```js
function* foo() {
    let bar = { a: 0, b: 0 };
    yield bar;

    bar = {...bar, a: bar.a + 1}
    yield bar;
    
    bar = {...bar, b: bar.b + 10}
    yield bar;
}

const baz = foo()
console.log([...baz])
```